# How can I answer a call on the browser with twilio javascript jdk

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am trying to answer a call that is routed through taskRouter through a worker with no luck.

I call the dequeue of reservation resource on the client, if I use a phone number to the To param works

```
reservation.dequeue(
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    "+1205...."
    (error, r) =>
      if error
        console.log(error)
      else
        console.log(r)
  )
```

But when I am trying to route to web browser it doesn't work, both of the followings don't work

```
reservation.dequeue(
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    "client:WK6dabefad96...."
    (error, r) =>
      if error
        console.log('error')
        console.log(error)
      else
        console.log('R')
        console.log(r)
  )

 reservation.dequeue(
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    null
    (error, r) =>
      if error
        console.log('error')
        console.log(error)
      else
        console.log('R')
        console.log(r)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that twilio initializes the call, do I need to answer it from the worker side?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to send those calls to browser than you need to setup a Twilio Client, you must also set up the devices. You can find more information on [Twilio Client documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript).

When generating the client access token while initializing the UI client (the softphone), that the **identity**  value matches the client name in the contact_uri of the worker attribute. e.g. `identity = 'WK*****'` , when creating the access token and `"contact_uri":"client:WK*****"` in the worker attribute. I would suggest to use a name in the contact_uri like `"contact_uri":"client:bilal"`.